# OOP PHP - accessing instances and methods

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to find a solution of my problem, but unsuccessfully. For example:

- I have one main class:

  ```
      class System {  
        public function loadClass($instance, $name)
        {
          $this->$instance = new $name;
        } 
      }
  ```

And I want, that I simply can load another class into main class called System.

```
        <?php
          $system = new System;
          $system->loadClass('db', 'database');
    ?>
```

It's working.. But I need to access all methods (and instances) of loaded class from any loaded class like this:

```
    <?php   
        class System {  
          public function loadClass($instance, $name)
          {
            $this->$instance = new $name;
          } 

          public function run()
          {
            echo $this->subA->methodA();
            echo $this->subB->methodB();      
          }
        }

        class subClassA extends System {
          function __construct()
          {
            echo $this->subB->methodB();    
          }

          public function methodA()
          {
            return 'okA';
          }
        }

        class subClassB extends System {
          function __construct()
          {
            echo $this->subA->methodA();
          }

          public function methodB()
          {
            return 'okB';
          }
        }

        $system = new System;

        $system->loadClass('subA', 'subClassA');
        $system->loadClass('subB', 'subClassB');

        $system->run();
?>
```

How it is possible without using static methods and instances?

Comment: All what you are doing is wrong. This stuff should be done automatically by SPL autoloader. And also, it violates the **Single-Responsibility Principle**

Comment: and also, System should not be extended, you'd only inject this one (`has-a` relationship) as it satisfies the `LSP`

Comment: `PSR-0` usually solve problems like this one.

Comment: I would agree that this is not a correct design as a proper Object Oriented solution.  Can you clarify the problem with maybe some examples of the actual entities that you're trying to get to interact?

Comment: I see that in question we have problem which follows by another real problem. What is the real problem?

Comment: @metal_fan Yes, autolader will be better. But the problem is, that all classes (objects) must by in one class (System).

methai For example, in Database class, I'm getting some config variables (for example from config object). I should get that like $this->config->getValue('dbType');.

Comment: Take a look on [IoC](http://www.slideshare.net/neraath/ioc-with-php-8833643) concept.

Comment: @mudrc Boostrapper **should not** be a class, this is a root of your problems. Aren't you inspired by CodeIgniter? You have already violated both the SRP and LSP (*SOLID principles*)

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it wrong. I'm beginner in OOP. I watched a lot of examples of OOP in PHP, but I don't found ideal structure. The only one thing I want is, that I can do the same thing, which I describe in the previous comment. Can anybody help me, with some structure of OOP, which will by ideal for this situation?